# SSO Authentication failed when click on the link but copy and paste working properly

Tags: c#

SSO Authentication failed when click on the link but copy and paste the link on the browser SSO login successfully in c#. Does anyone have idea about this one?? Suppose any header need to add from my side?

SSO Authentication need to be success when click on the link

Comment: There's too little details in the question, no indication of the protocol, no example of a problematic link. Please, edit your question to provide more information, or else it will probably be closed.